# How to find missing externals for a new package

Tags: packages, texlive, installing

I am currently trying to install packages glossaries and glossaries-extra. Everything is fine until I try to compile (using pdflatex) a .tex document.  Each time the compiler requests that I add a new package (e.g. mfirstuc.sty, datatool-base.sty) Is there any resource that lists all the files that are required for a new package to work?

Is there a way similar to apt install package where all required externals are included in the install?

Thanks

PS ubuntu 22.04 with TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian

Comment: as you are using TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian you should be updating via apt not something similar to apt

Comment: Not much luck there: sudo apt install glossaries glossaries-extra
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package glossaries
E: Unable to locate package glossaries-extra
abraca@P7920-Vite:~$

Comment: Welcome TeX.SE @clinton-winant I don't use Ubuntu, but I think you should try something like `sudo apt update` then, on success, `sudo apt install texlive-full`

Comment: no apt does  not work at that level of granularity, you can do  query to see which apt package it is in (or use `texlive-full) a quick google search suggests this https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/texlive-latex-extra/filelist

Comment: @gildux  Your suggestion worked.  Thanks so much to the two of you.  If you care to rephrase your comment as an answer I will mark it as accepted

Comment: Done. I hope it's complete and well written (English isn't my native and sometimes I make strange mistakes.) Please, add `installing` and `texlive` tags to your question, it helps categorisation and advanced search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure, but it's like things didn't change a lot. (I've tried it with older Ubuntu versions and Debian too.) So here are the steps to install TeX Live from console prompt of this family of distributions.

1. Run system update in order to rebuild the system repo cache and update the packages lists

   ```shell
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install currently available TeX Live : TeX packages, as well as the macro languages ​​LaTeX and ConTeXt based on them, plus the applications Metafont, MetaPost, BibTeX, and a large number of character sets.

   ```shell
   sudo apt install texlive-full
   ```

   Insead of `texlive-full`, one can also choose some available alternatives:

   - `texlive` (without any -suffix) for basic and some extra packages
   - one of the following particular composition as per your profession (note that they are all bundled in the -full set automatically):

     - `texlive-publishers`
     - `texlive-science`
     - `texlive-pstricks`
     - `texlive-humanities`
     - `texlive-pictures`
     - `texlive-xetex`
     - `texlive-metapost`
     - `texlive-music`
3. Now, go write and compile your documents.